# Ground overlay mismatch occurred after migration from v2 to v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, migration

My groundoverlay maps (projection: WGS_Web-1984_World_Mercator, 3857) works perfect in v2, but mismatch occurred after migrating to v3 although the bounding coordinates remain unchanged. The problem is that changing the bounding coordinates does not help as the projections do not match any more (they match at bounds, not in the middle). However, the img from my png file matches the screenshot of the Google map well in Photoshop. It looks like that the projection of my groundoverlay img is transformed in the overlay process. Is the projection in API v3 different from v2?

My v3 code is here:

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(53.008742,-124.120850);
var pngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(48.4367, -139.0402), new    google.maps.LatLng(59.99008, -114.1095));
var ovl_fn = 'http://climatemodels.forestry.ubc.ca/climatebc/overlays/climate/MAP_1961_1990.png';

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {  center: myCenter,  zoom:6, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
  var matMap = new  google.maps.GroundOverlay(ovl_fn, pngBounds);
  matMap.setMap(map);
}
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```